# Finite subsets of vector space under affine group action

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, affine-geometry

For a field $K$ and natural numbers $n, m$, define $A(n,m,K) \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ as follows: For an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $K$, the group of affine automorphisms of $V$ acts on the set of $m$-element subsets of $V$. Let $A(n,m,K)$ be the number of orbits of this action.

For example, $A(n, 1, K) = 1$ and $A(n, 2, K) = 1$, provided $n \geq 1$.

What is known about the numbers $A(n,m,K)$?

Comment: For $n=1$ and a basis $\{b\}$ of $V$, the $|K|-2$ ordered triples $(0,b,\lambda b)$ for $\lambda \in K \setminus \{0,1\}$ are in distinct orbits under the action of $G$, so  $A(1,3,K)$ is at least $(|K|-2)/6$, and a few calculations with small finite $K$ suggest that it is equal to $\lceil (|K|-2)/6 \rceil$.

Comment: What do you know about what happens if I take the general linear group instead of the general affine group?